# angular2 multiselect dropdown (version 2.3.0) with lazy load included onSelect of item browser become unresponsive

Tags: angular, select, dropdown, multi-select

**app-module.ts**

```
import { AngularMultiSelectModule } from 'angular2-multiselect-dropdown/angular2-multiselect-dropdown';
```

**HTML**

```
<angular2-multiselect
   #mulitSelectDropdown
   [data]="myOptions" 
   [hidden]="!searchTextHide" 
   [(ngModel)]="selectedItemsMember" 
   [settings]="multiSelectDropdownSettingsMemeber" 
   (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)" 
   (onDeSelect)="OnItemDeSelect($event)" 
   (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)" 
   (onDeSelectAll)="onDeSelectAll($event)"
   [ngClass]="{'disabled': myOptions.length === 0}"
   (onOpen)="addScrollListner(1)">
</angular2-multiselect>
```

**ngOnInit**

```
 this.multiSelectDropdownSettingsLevel = {
        singleSelection: false,
        text: "Select Hierarchy",
        selectAllText: 'Select All',
        unSelectAllText: 'UnSelect All',
        enableSearchFilter: true,
        classes: "singleSelect"
    };
```

**Function call**

```
getProductMemeberData(levelID, searchText){
    this._productHierarchyService.getProductMember(levelID, searchText)
        .map((data: any) => data.json())
        .subscribe(
        (data: any) => { 
           this.IsFilterClearBtnDisable = false;
           data.forEach(result => {
              this.myOptions.push({
                id: result.sl,
                itemName: result.itemName
              });
           });
         },
     err => console.log(err), // error
   );
}
```

Here when I try to Select any item of the dropdown browser become unresponsive with 3000 records in it, With no exceptions/erro. I am using angular2-multiselect-dropdown(version 2.3.0) by CuppaLabs. Any Idea how to resolve this would be a great help.

Comment: for the 3000 records. I would suggest using `autocomplete` instead of `dropdown`. OR `material chips` would be better.

Answer (score -1):

Please change configuration settings as below

1. Change  [settings]="multiSelectDropdownSettingsMemeber" to [settings]="multiSelectDropdownSettingsLevel"
2. Set lazyLoading flag to true and enable enableSearchFilter
   this.multiSelectDropdownSettingsLevel = {
       singleSelection: false,
       text: "Select Hierarchy",
       selectAllText: 'Select All',
       unSelectAllText: 'UnSelect All',
       enableSearchFilter: true,
       classes: "singleSelect",
       lazyLoading : true,
       enableSearchFilter: true
   };